# Execute function with Hex Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hex, windows-forms-designer

I have a simple vb function that does Hello World
I converted this function to hex and added hex to plain text file
The next thing I did was add a text file to resources

I have a button added to Form1, I want it to convert the code from the resource file and execute the function when the button is clicked - that is, show Hello World

205075626c6963205368617265642046756e6374696f6e2048656c6c6f576f726c6428290a2020202020202020496e746572616374696f6e2e4d7367426f78282248656c6c6f20576f726c6422290a202020202020202044696d206f626a65637430204173204f626a656374203d204e6f7468696e670a202020202020202052657475726e206f626a656374300a20202020456e642046756e6374696f6e

```
 Public Shared Function HelloWorld()
        Interaction.MsgBox("Hello World")
        Dim object0 As Object = Nothing
        Return object0
    End Function
```

How can I do it ?
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you really want to do? Does it amount to running the VB.NET compiler on a text file?

Comment: And so, I have a HelloWorld function in a hex file, this function in theory shows a MsgBox with the message Hello World
I have a button on Form1 and when clicked, I want the compiler to convert the hex code and I get a Hello World message

Comment: I think that what you want to do is included in [Run VB.net code from text file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e5fd95e-a327-4b00-a0e4-ba52a7f476d3/run-vbnet-code-from-text-file?forum=vblanguage), and, if not, then it will give you more things to investigate to achieve your goal.

Comment: It's about the same
But you don't quite understand what I mean
Converting vb code from a text file is not so difficult, but I don’t understand the following, I have a text file and it contains not code, but hex code and I need to try to convert hex to code and then compile

Comment: What do *you* mean by "hex code"? It seems to me that you have converted the bytes to text representations of those bytes, e.g. "A" -> "41", and I was not able to understand from the question as written why you'd do that.

Comment: I used this site to convert the text of the vb function that outputs Hello World to hex code
https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php
I copied the text I received and added it to a text document
Next, I added a text document to my project's resources
now I have one task left
Understand how to compile code from a hex text document when clicking on a button
Well, either I can use something like dim blah blah blah for hex code
and then try to compile it

Comment: You can add the "text of the vb function" to the resource file. There's no need to add an extra complication to it that you then have to immediately undo. You *had* one task, but you turned it into two. ;)

Comment: If you can provide a little more detail on the problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to give better suggestions on a good approach.

Comment: Question I have, if you’re adding this text file to the project resource,  what exactly is the point of trying to first decode the hex, then executing whatever other code is?  All in all seems a little pointless.